# When are Hilbert schemes connected by piecewise smooth curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, hilbert-schemes

Are there examples of Hilbert scheme $H$ of curves in $\mathbb{P}^3$ such that there exists an irreducible component $L$ of $H$ such that for any two points in $L$, there exist smooth projective curves $C_1,...,C_n$ such that $C_i \cap C_{i-1} \not= \emptyset$ and $\cup_{i=1}^n C_i$ passes through both of them?

Comment: 1. I think you want to assume the curves are rational. : ) 2. Doesn't the Hilbert scheme of lines / degree 1 genus 0 curves, which is just the Grassmanian, which is rationally connected, provide an example? More generally, any degree and genus such that complete intersections form an irreducible component will work.

Comment: @Sawin: Thank you for your answer. In response to your comment 1, I know that my question clashes with the title, but I wanted to give slightly more freedom in the question. I wanted to include the bigger class of smooth curves rather than restricting to just rational curves although the title implies that.

Comment: All connected schemes are connected by smooth curves in this manner. At least all projective ones are, and Hilbert schemes are projective.

Comment: @user46578: As Will points out, your question as it stands doesn't make sense. Please edit.

Comment: Have you read Hartshorne's paper "Connectedness of the Hilbert scheme"? I seem to recall that he proves something along the lines of what you want.

Comment: @Loughran:Thanks for your comment. No, I have not read it. I will have look into it.

Comment: @Sawin: Could you please explain/give reference as to why any two points on a projective scheme can be connected by piecewise smooth curves, as defined in the question? Note that, the projective scheme need not be smooth.